# How to get 'winget' command in windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, winget

I am running into this problem when I try to execute 'winget' in power shell.

```
❯ winget
winget: The term 'winget' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I am running Windows 11 with the latest update.

And when I go to 'App Installer' in Window Store. It said I already have 'App Installer' installed.

Can you please tell me how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you running the command from within a Command Prompt or PowerShell Prompt? In my experience you cannot run it from a PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Try installing [Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.appxbundle](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/download/v1.3.2691/Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle).  1.3.2691 is a stable version that mentions specifically it supports Windows 11.

Comment: I tried installing ^ link. I get a window saying 'For proper functioning of the app, try to launch a Windows app package.  And then when I open a new PowerShell, it still say 'winget' is not recognized.

Comment: Did you try `Add-AppxPackage -RegisterByFamilyName -MainPackage Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe`? See [Install winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget).